# Can i multiply an [6x1] matrix with an [6x6] in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I wish to multiply the first matrix

```
float X[6] =
{
  x,  //Position
  y,  //Position
  z,  //Position
  _x, //Velocity
  _y, //Velocity
  _z  //Velocity
};
```

with the second one. (where t = 2)

```
float F[6][6] = {
  { 1, 0, 0, t, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 1, 0, 0, t, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, t },
  { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
};
```

which is actually `[6x1] * [6x6]`

Is it posible? Or should i also convert the first matrix at `[6x6]` first?

Comment: That depends. What do you actually want the end result to be?

Comment: Based on the semantics of the variables in $X$, I would guess you actually want to compute the matrix-vector product $FX$, which is $6\times6$ times $6\times1$, and would give you `{x + t*_x, y + t*_y, z + t*_z, _x, _y, _z}`.

Comment: Maths format would be nicer than computer code.

Comment: What do these *arrays* represent? (I wouldn't call them matrices, otherwise the product is not defined since the dot product of vectors in different dimensions is not defined.)  What exactly do you want the result to be? Can you write out clearly using MathJax to display?

Comment: @Allawonder Actually i hear that first time. I guess i will have to give it a try for my next post.

Comment: @Allawonder Until we get an explanation of what the desired result is, I see no reason not to call them matrices. If the solution is as simple as what Kraig suggests in the answer below (and I personally believe that it is), then they truly behave entirely like matrices.

Comment: @Arthur Actually i am trying to implement the prediction phase of an Kalman filter where x equals the state vector and F represents the state transition matrix

Comment: @OrElse So if you want the result to be `{x + _x*t, y + _y*t, z + _z*t, _x, _y, _z}` (either as a row or as a column), then the answer below by Kraig is the right one for you.

Comment: @Arthur If they are matrices, then the product (as required in OP) is *not* defined. Hence my not calling them matrices leaves open the possibility of defining our products anyhow we wish.

Comment: @Allawonder I think it's better to say "That matrix product isn't the way matrix products usually are" rather than "those things clearly aren't matrices, since you're not multiplying them the way matrices ought to be multiplied". At least as long as it seems plausible that the real answer actually treats them as matrices. But you do you.

Comment: @Arthur Well, that's what you think, but I don't think so. I guess this boils down to whether you think *every* rectangular array is a matrix. I don't like to think so.

Comment: @Allawonder Neither do I. But this time I was pretty certain the mistake was in writing the product the right way, not in the idea of using matrix products in the first place. If that had turned out to not be the case, I would stop calling them matrices too.

Comment: @Arthur I see. But I wasn't as certain as you that the problem was in the ordering. For one, I didn't find the presentation appealing to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply it the other way around. You can multiply a 6x6 square matrix by a 6x1 column matrix. Suppose you are multiplying two matricies, the left one is $n\times m$ and the right one is $\ell\times j$. This multiplication fails by normal matrix multiplication rules if $m\neq \ell$. That is, you can only multiply an $n\times m$ by an $m\times j$ matrix. The resulting matrix has a dimensionality $n\times j$. There are other forms of matrix multiplication which may be applicable to you, but if you require normal matrix multiplication, you must follow this procedure.

If you are looking to get a square matrix back, this procedure will not work. You will get back a $6\times1$ column matrix by following this procedure.

Comment: See my comment above. While one can guess (and I think you're right), it is still unknown what the desired _result_ of the multiplication should be, and therefore we can't really tell what the correct operation is. For instance, if one does not assume or guess anything, then it is just as correct to transpose the column into a row and keep the multiplication order.

Comment: @Arthur I was in the process of editing when you replied. I suggested looking into forms of multiplication, but matrix multiplication is *typically* considered to be what I've described.

Comment: I think i got your point. In such case the result will be an [n x  j] matrix. Right?

Comment: @Kraig the thing I described falls just as neatly into _typical_ matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Arthur if you lookup matrix multiplication, the wikipedia article does not mention other forms. I know there is the Kronecker product, which might also be of interest, but while that is a form of matrix multiplication, it has its own name so is generally referred to as such.

Comment: Did you actually read what I suggested? Transpose the column into a row and keep the multiplication order. That makes it into a $1\times 6$ times $6\times 6$ matrix product.

Comment: @Arthur ah i only saw your first comment. My apologies